# Features : export content types with FieldCollection

Tags: features, entities

When I try to export my content type using Features, it works. But when I import it on another Drupal installation, I've got an exception :

```
Exception : Invalid field name given: **my_field** is not a Field Collection field. in FieldCollectionItemEntity->__construct() (line 119 in **path_to_module**\field_collection\field_collection.module)
```

That's strange, because IT IS a Field Collection, and it worked fine on the first Drupal installation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: For clarity, you mean it exported fine from the first Drupal installation, and the problem is with importing into another Drupal installation?  Or have you imported into another one without issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solution to this problem, the first one is a bug in the module that can be fixed via this patch https://drupal.org/node/1084268

The second solution fixes a problem caused by orphan fields in field_collection_item table.
First try removing **my_field** via drupal interface, if it didn't exists try 
 searching your **my_field** in this table, if it existed , delete it

- NOTE : the solution is dirty one, it worked for but it may have side effects, backup your database before trying it